# Google Sheet Query smarter way to get multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas, google-sheets-query, regex

I use a spreadsheet where I want a list of items which contains multiple criteria.
(I need all cells in a range which contains the letter 'a - g'

The formula I use now is

```
=query(Planning!G5:G37;  "select * where G contains 'a' or G contains 'b' or G contains 'c'   or ............  " )
```

What I want is the query get the criteria out of a list or an array, but I couldn't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- you can use regex if you do it like this:

  ```
  =QUERY(Planning!G5:G37, "where G matches '[a-g]'", 0)
  ```

  ```
  =QUERY(Planning!G5:G37, "where G matches 'a|b|c|d|e|f|g'", 0)
  ```

  [image: 0]

---

- to mimic **`contains`** do:

  ```
  =QUERY(G5:G37, "where G matches '[a-g]*|.*[a-g]'", 0)
  ```

  [image: 0]

Comment: Thank you, that work good for me.